# Was there ever an ending to Pushing Daisies?

Tags: pushing-daisies

I remember that I was very sad to hear that they cancelled *Pushing Daisies*. But did the story have an end that was in some kind of script?

I know the fanbase isn't that big but maybe someone knows it.

Comment: I hope so. That tacked-on final montage clumsily compiled from old scenes was quite appalling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bryan Fuller had [plans for the "back nine" episodes](http://www.blastr.com/2009/05/bryan_fuller_how_pushing.php) of the second season, but then the series got cancelled; hence the montage at the end of the last episode (which replaced a cliffhanger).

There were plans to [continue the show in comic form](http://splashpage.mtv.com/2009/04/21/pushing-daisies-tv-series-finds-life-after-cancellation-at-dc-comics/), but then shortly before the first issue was supposed to be released, DC closed its Wildstorm imprint (the publisher of the comic).

AFAIK Fuller never released any details on these storylines, and considering that every now and then he continues to push for a Pushing Daisies revival (on Starz or Netflix or perhaps a Broadway musical or a Kickstarter-funded movie etc.), I suspect he still has hopes of revisiting the series and that's why he isn't spilling any secrets.